# Datadog SSH integration error: Server 'localhost' not found in known_hosts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ssh-keys, datadog

With [reference to Datadog document for SSH integration](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/ssh_check/?tabs=host) I am trying to use it, but getting the following error :

```
Datadog’s ssh_check integration is reporting: Instance #ssh_check:fbecff0ac9464f00[ERROR]: [{"message": "Server 'localhost' not found in 
known_hosts", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/base/checks/base.py\", 
line 841, in run\n self.check(instance)\n File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datadog_checks/ssh_check/ssh_check.py\",
 line 67, in check\n client.connect(\n File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/client.py\", line 415, in connect\n self._policy.missing_host_key(\n File \"/opt/datadog-agent/embedded/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/client.py\", line 823, in missing_host_key\n raise 
SSHException(\nparamiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Server 'localhost' not found in known_hosts\n"}]
```

As per my understanding of this **error: Server 'localhost' not found in known_hosts**, I tried `ssh myusername@localhost` and **Permanently added localhost to the list of known hosts.** I am still getting the same error. How can I fix this issue?

Note: I am trying to implement an ssh check, in Datadog for my AWS EC2 instance ie I want to alert when there is an ssh issue on my servers

[image: Datadog screenshot]

Comment: "my localhost is an AWS ec2 instance" So you are running the `ssh` command on the same EC2 instance you are trying to `ssh` into? Why? For what possible purpose?

Comment: You are probably adding to the known hosts of your specific EC2 user account, not the account that the DataDog service is running under. However running this on the same server you are trying to monitor does NOT provide good monitoring of SSH connectivity to your server. For example this would always succeed even though a network firewall rule was blocking SSH.

Comment: I am using hosted datadog service and as per my understanding of this doc https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/ssh_check/?tabs=host I am running dd agent on my aws instance, dd agent is working and other metrics are also coming so no firewall issue

Comment: I'm talking about incoming SSH connectivity being blocked by a firewall, which is totally unrelated to the agent metrics going from the server out to datadog. Also, as per the description of the ssh agent: "This check lets you monitor SSH connectivity to remote hosts" It is specifically for monitoring **remote** hosts, yet you are using to monitor localhost.

Comment: @MarkB I appreciate your support,  so should I open port 22 of security group of aws Host to be monitored? But if it's security group related issue then error should be connection timeout right? Or should I change localhost to datadog URL as I am using hosted dd service?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245911/discussion-between-ashish-karpe-and-mark-b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Added following line to config

```
add_missing_keys: true
```